# Updating device takes so long

Tags: gpu, system, opencl

I'm using Blender 2.93,
I'm enabling *System > Cycles > Render Devices* to *OpenCL*. From 10 am until 12pm, its 2 hours already, but its still updating devices is this normal?

my system specification:
Processor: Intel 5 gen 11
RAM : 16GB
Graphic card: Intel Iris Xe Graphics

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You are updating devices in Blender? I don't know if I understand this correctly...

Comment: Considering you have an Intel XE GPU and Open CL is only supported for AMD graphics cards, I'd say it might never actually finish.